# Youtube Video Upload using Java API Client - Connection Timed Out

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube API v3 for uploading video using Java API Client

I am getting following error several times - Although video is uploaded on YouTube-

```
IOException 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x79899a18: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:689)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:316)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:417)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.nexstreaming.sdk2.nexsns.Youtube$5.doInBackground(Youtube.java:475)
at com.nexstreaming.sdk2.nexsns.Youtube$5.doInBackground(Youtube.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

That could be related to a known bug
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5700